# Uploading file through an action of a controller - two forms in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

The problem is I have two forms in the same view. The controller is `Users` and I have two actions for the two forms: Edit and UploadPhoto.

I have been using the Edit portion for awhile and it's working. Now I want to allow users to upload their photo on the same page. There is a separate button for saving the user information and another for saving the picture.

[image]

The page model is `@model sportingbiz.Models.ViewModels.UserEditViewModel`

The second form

```
<fieldset title="Upload photo">
    <legend>Change Profile Picture</legend>
    <div>
        @using(Html.BeginForm("UploadPhoto", "Users", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/noprofilepic.jpg")" 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="photoFile" />
                    <br /><br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>                
        }
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Controller

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    UsersRepository usersRepo = new UsersRepository();


    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public void UploadPhoto(HttpPostedFile photoFile)
    {
        if (photoFile == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (photoFile.ContentLength <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        string filename = Path.GetFileName(photoFile.FileName);
        if (Path.GetExtension(filename) == "")
            return;

    }
}
```

When I click upload my page navigates to `http://localhost/mvcapp/Users/UploadPhoto` with a blank screen. What I want is to return to the Edit page and probably show errors to the user that file was not uploaded. Features like `ModelState.IsValid` or `ModelState.AddModelError`

There is also no option of returning the same view e.g. return View(model)

Am I doing this wrong way? Some suggestion is to use Ajax uploader or Uploader. Am also thinking of separating the forms putting the Upload portion in its own view. Can PartialView help in this respect

Comment: do you wan to do this using BeginForm, otherwise you can use Jquery Uploader.

Comment: Your 'second form' is a field-set, you're missing the Form around it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's within the fieldset - `@using(Html.BeginForm(`

Comment: Right, missed that. Seems inside-out though.

Comment: Have you had a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/379980/Fancy-ASP-NET-MVC-Image-Uploader ? That seems a pretty nice solution

Answer (score 1):

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public void UploadPhoto(HttpPostedFile photoFile)
{
```

An Action with a `void` return is very strange. Make it return an `ActionResult` and determine on each branch where you want to go.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public void UploadPhoto(HttpPostedFile photoFile)
{
    if (photoFile == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ErrorPage");
    }
    ...

    var viewModel = ...;   // but your've lost the Edit part
    return View(viewModel);
 }
```

Comment: _but you've lost the Edit part_. That's exactly what I mean. Situation where user did not choose a file and clicked save - I have to redirect to error page?

Comment: For a null/empty file you can return to the View as well. But the user will lose what's been edited. Follows from your design: Save A _or_ Save B.

Comment: Can one achieve this with PartialView?

Comment: No a Partial View helps you with rendering, this is about Posting data.

Answer (score 1):

try to validate the using jquery like below, which will make sure that user are force to select some file...

lets us assume you a view like below

```
<input type="file" name="Document" id="imgFile" style="height:25px;"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit"/>
```

below is the jquery to validate

```
$('#imgFile').change(function() {
    if ( ! $('#imgFile').val() ) {
    alert('Chose a file!');
    return false;
 }
});
```

or you can do this same on the Button click like below

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    if ( ! $('#imgFile').val() ) {
    alert('Chose a file!');
    return false;
 }
});
```

hope this might help you...

Answer (score 0):

you uplode your image like that

```
 public void UploadPhoto(HttpPostedFile photoFile)
 {}
```

i think you should little bit change you code like this

```
 public void UploadPhoto(HttpPostedFileBase photoFile)
 {}
```